# Code behind safety ASP.NET .CS

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm new to web programming and have a question about code behind in ASP.NET C#. How safe is it from someone seeing what's in it? The reason I ask is the program I'm linking this website to requires me to create an object that takes in my admin credentials (It does this in the background thousands of times or I would just prompt for creds). It uses the credentials to create things dynamically. I'm 99.99% sure this is highly unsafe to hard code my credentials into the page but I figured I would ask.

Comment: Step 1. Go research forms authentication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The code behind files and raw aspx files are protected from being retrieved by the web server, so as long as you control console and file share access to the server you are relatively safe.

Still, it is not considered really safe. You should set up the application pool of the site to run under a specific account and then give that account the necessary rights. Having services using ordinary user accounts is considered bad practice. Each service should have its own account, with least possible rights.

Answer (score 3):

You should put your credentials in your web.config (or you can move them into separate files like AppSettings.config or ConnectionStrings.config etc). The server <strike>will</strike> should never serve these.

This might be helpful: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c2kcht0(v=VS.100).aspx

This tells you how you can can go one step further and encrypt these so they do not store plain text password etc:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx

Comment: "the server will never serve these"... At least until it does: http://www.gdssecurity.com/l/b/2010/10/04/padbuster-v0-3-and-the-net-padding-oracle-attack/  You can't trust anything.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET pages are compiled before sending the page over HTTP. This is secure. But if the user can access the file system, you have another problem on your hands.

Answer (score 2):

It is "safe".  IIS (by default) does not serve up .cs files.

Another option is to precompile the site and then just drop the .aspx files on the web server.

Comment: IIS doesn't serve .cs files, true, but it's still possible someone will find an exploit to get at them (same with the web.config). As far as I know the best solution is to place sensitive info in an encrypted web.config file.

Comment: True, still not really "safe", but the best solution is likely to give the user for the application pool have the permissions necessary to do what is needed.  That way the credentials can't be accessed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Putting sensitive information into .cs files in ASP.NET is by default not a risky process as ASP.NET does not give access to .cs files from the client side (if you don't change it explictly), however, be sure that if there is a server error, custom errors reporting mode does not send the lines of the code to the client (which is extremely useful when debugging, and extremely risky when you release it to the public) or anyone may be able to read your sensitive information if an exception is thrown near those lines.

Answer (score 1):

There are various levels of "safe" here.

Yes, IIS is configured to not serve up .cs files or .config files.  That said, there are [attack vectors](http://www.gdssecurity.com/l/b/2010/10/04/padbuster-v0-3-and-the-net-padding-oracle-attack/) which have proven successful in getting IIS to deliver those files into the evil doers hands.

First off, I wouldn't deploy .cs files to the server.  If possible convert the web site to a web application and deploy it compiled.  Of course, .net code can be [decompiled](http://www.reflector.net/) ([and here](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx)); so you should also look into [obfuscation](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator).  However even [obfuscated code can be decompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226695/wanted-a-tool-for-decompiling-obfuscated-net-code) but it's generally harder to read. ;)

Note that each level isn't really "secure".  It just makes it more difficult.

The real answer is to not store the credentials on the server at all and require them to be provided by the client over an encrypted transport.  Certainly you could cache them in memory, but even [that has proven insecure to those with physical access](http://hackaday.com/2008/02/21/breaking-disk-encryption-with-ram-dumps/).

At the end of the day, ask yourself how valuable the keys are and how much money/time you can invest in securing the system.  There's usually a balance somewhere.